# How can I match this using RegEx?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to create regex to match all of the date, description and amount. I almost have it, BUT the line that ends in "187927.42" is messing up and matching on "187927.42" instead of "-2,931.25".

How can I match "12/22/15", "BNF:eeeerere TECHNOLOGIES ID:1231231231 BNF BK:K OTAK MAHINDRA BANK
LTD ID:INKKBK0000810 PMT DET:16 2105412 117.25 HOURS POP SERVICES /FXREF/TE-3-8-15", "-2,931.25"? Along with all the other transaction lines?

Here is the expression I came up with `/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})\s+(.*?)\s+([0-9\,\-]+\.\d{2}) *(?=\d\d\/|$(?!\n-?[\d\.]+$))/mis`

See this example here https://regex101.com/r/X9HeWv/1

```
12/17/15 Online Banking transfer to CHK 4958 Confirmation# 1231231231 -300.00
12/18/15 Online Banking transfer to CHK 4958 Confirmation# 1231231231 -200.00
12/18/15 THE HARTFORD DES:NWerfLSCIC ID:13975910 INDN:wesedrfr TECHNOLGOIES CO
ID:9942902727 CCD
-78.75
12/21/15 Online Banking transfer to CHK 4958 Confirmation# 1231231231 -50.00
12/22/15 WIRE TYPE:FX OUT DATE:151228 TIME:0944 ET TRN:2015122200194472 FX:INR 187927.42
64.1117 BNF:eeeerere TECHNOLOGIES ID:1231231231 BNF BK:K OTAK MAHINDRA BANK
LTD ID:INKKBK0000810 PMT DET:16 2105412 117.25 HOURS POP SERVICES /FXREF/TE-3-8-15
-2,931.25
12/22/15 Online Banking transfer to CHK 4958 Confirmation# 1231231231 -6,000.00
12/28/15 FORD CREDIT DES:FORDCREDIT ID:XXXXXXXXX INDN:werwe wer CO
ID:7587806091 PPD
-1,180.00
12/28/15 SC EVERCODER SOF DES:IAT PAYPAL ID:J222226DW9MWA INDN:werwer eeee CO
ID:XXXXXXXXXC IAT PMT INFO: WEB 000000000000000900
-9.00
12/29/15 Online Banking transfer to CHK 4958 Confirmation# 1231231231 -200.00
```

**UPDATE:**

So by adding a condition requiring a thousands separator when the number is greater than one thousand worked.  But I feel like that's not the best approach.

```
(\-?(?!0+\.00)(?=.{1,9}(\.|$))(?!0(?!\.))\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)

(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})\s+(.*?)\s+(\-?(?!0+\.00)(?=.{1,9}(\.|$))(?!0(?!\.))\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?) *(?=\d\d\/|$(?!\n+$))
```

https://regex101.com/r/T8sxkh/1

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems

Comment: If a transfer can span over multiple lines there is always the possibility that it is ambiguous if the transfer description contains a number, then a newline, followed by a part which perfectly looks like a new transfer (date + text + number). Using this format for processing of account data is inherently dangerous.

Comment: What language or tool or library are you using to parse this file?

Comment: @melpomene PHP.  I know I can use PHP to find this, but I really wanted to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- Every record consists of three parts: A date, a description, and an amount.
- The date is in the format `dd/dd/dd` and is always followed by a space.
- The amount is always negative.
- The amount is always followed by the end of a line.
- The amount uses `,` as a thousands separator and always includes `.` and two decimal places.
- The description can contain newlines, but it never contains what looks like the start of a new record (i.e. a newline followed by a date).
- There is either a space or a newline between the description and the amount.

Here's the best thing I managed to come up with:

```
^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}) (.*?)[ \n](-\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d\d)(?=\Z|\n\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} )
```

Flags: `msg`

Explanation:

```
^  # beginning of line (with m flag)
(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})  # date (which we capture)
[ ]  # a literal space
(.*?)  # description (can match across lines with s flag)
       # it is completely free-form; we match until we find something that looks like an amount
[ \n]  # separator between description and amount, space or newline
(-\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d\d)  # the actual amount
(?=  # followed by either:
  \Z  # end of the input (i.e. end-of-string or newline followed by end-of-string)
|    # or:
  \n \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}[ ]  # a newline followed by a date and a space, i.e. the start of a new record
)
```

Live demo: https://regex101.com/r/X9HeWv/2